# ASP MVC4 / Relation between classes on creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, models

Hello everybody and thanks for reading and tryin to help.

I'm a beginner in asp.

I Have two classes :

```
public class Organisation
{

    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public string Nom_Organisation { get; set; }
    public string Adresse_Organisation { get; set; }
    public string Mail_Organisation { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date_Ajout_Org { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contrat> contract { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Ticket_Org { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Interlocuteur> Interlocuteurs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Environnement> Environments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Outils> Outils { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Support> Supports { get; set; }




    public Organisation() 
    {

    }

}
```

and

```
public class Contrat
{
    public int ContratId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date_Conclu { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string Commentaire { get; set; }

    public virtual Organisation Orga{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TypeContratId { get; set; }

    public virtual TypeContrat Type { get; set; }


    public Contrat()
    {


    }
}
```

I want to create an Organisation then add to it the contract. The thing is that i really don't see how. I create the Organisation with the generated controller but when i try to think about a way to create the Contract by sending to it the Organisation ID.

I want to add to the default generated table a button that send to the action that create the contract with the ID of the organisation selected.

Hope that u've understood my question! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code for the controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use Entities Framework. If so, then you need not worry about it
just create Organisation and to add Contrat in `ICollection<Contrat> contract`

```
  Organisation newOrg = new Organisation();
  newOrg.contract  = new List<Contrat>();
  newOrg.contract.add(new contract())
  context.Organisation.Add(newOrg);
  context.save();
```

Or you can use Guid how other way:

```
change to:
public int OrganisationId { get; set; } => public Guid OrganisationId { get; set; }

Organisation newOrg = new Organisation();
newOrg.OrganisationId =  Guid.New();    
contract newContract = new contract();
newContract.OrganisationId = newOrg.OrganisationId;
context.Organisation.Add(newOrg);
context.save();
```